# How to use location marking in leaflet package in R

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have added two markers on leaflet map, and I want to link those markers (like travelling from one location to the other). How can I do that?

The code that I used to create markers is provided below:

```
p <- leaflet()
p <- p %>%
  addTiles()
p <- p %>% 
  addMarkers(lat = 32.051960, lng = 118.778030)
p <- p %>%
  addMarkers(lat = 33.6028, lng = 73.0646)
p
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `gcIntermediate` function from the `geosphere` package to create curved lines in `leaflet`. You can use the following code:

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(geosphere)
gcIntermediate(c(118.778030, 32.051960), c(73.0646, 33.6028),
               n=100, 
               addStartEnd=TRUE,
               sp=TRUE) %>% 
  leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(lat = 32.051960, lng = 118.778030) %>%
  addMarkers(lat = 33.6028, lng = 73.0646) %>%
  addPolylines()
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your response. Can you please explain your code a bit. why is the 'group' variable needed.  If I remove 'group = ~group' I get the same response, just that the line in a bit lighter.

Secondly, I am new to leaflet and learning this was very exciting for me. However, this was not what  I exactly wanted. I wanted lines over the top (line travelling via airlines). Is it possible to do here?

Comment: @SalmanVirani, I changed my code to curved lines using the `geosphere` package for in `leaflet`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out in the leaflet package

Comment: No problem! Always good to update your packages.

Comment: Hi, Quinten, I am actually new to stack overflow. I recently got two negative points on a question, and after that I am unable to ask any question. Can you please help out in any way if possible.